# v.dissolve (and other scripts) not in GRASS path

Tags: grass-gis

I see that I have the v.dissolve module in my grass64/scripts dir, but it is not found in my path from the GRASS command line.  I have the GRASS_ADDON_PATH environment variable set:
GRASS_ADDON_PATH=/usr/local/grass-6.4.1/scripts/

And the module itself is located in:
/usr/local/grass-6.4.1/scripts/v.dissolve

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Roger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to hear this will be resolved soon, Markus.  I found traffic from 2009 where you and I had discussed this problem then.  I'd just stopped using GRASS since then and forgotten the solution.

Just so that I can close this question, the answer to this is to place the scripts (like v.dissolve) in your PATH.  The easiest way I've come up with to do this is to move the executables out of their directories under grass64/scripts and into a tmp directory. Then delete the directories under grass64/scripts and move all of the exeutables back into that dir.  As long as you have the GRASS_ADDON_PATH set, you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes - or you apply the change which I linked above or simply grab the snapshot 6.4.2svn from the link above :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem which we have solved post-6.4.1 (should be [this](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/changeset/47869) change). It should work fine in the upcoming GRASS GIS 6.4.2 release.

You may get the nightly binary snapshot here: http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass64/
which includes the fix.

Comment: Did you try the nightly binary snapshot? All should be working now.